# Different Tab Bars when switching to different application function Swift Xcode 7

Tags: user-interface, swift2, uitabbarcontroller, xcode7, uitabbar

I have a tabbed application in Xcode 7, written in Swift 2.

It is a job search application. When you initially open the open you are brought to the job browse/search function. In one of the tabs you are able to select "Switch to Recruiter."

I would like to have this recruiter function in the app with a separate tab bar menu.

I've tried adding an additional tab bar controller in the storyboard as well as creating a new storyboard with a new tab bar controller and linking to it from the initial storyboard. In both instances, the original tab bar and the new tab bar are shown stacked at the bottom of the screen.

I obviously would like only the recruiter version of the tab bar to be shown when they are in that section of the app.

Does anyone have any suggestions for the best way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's as simple as creating 2 separate tabbars.
Made an [example project](https://github.com/4oby/multipleTabBarExample).

Comment: Great thanks! Should have done this from the beginning.